# GPSbabel: how do I define the layout of my input data

Tags: data, format, gpsbabel

I have collected GPS data on a journey by extracting it every second from the $GPRMC NMEA sentence, with each reading saved in the form:

```
time,latitude,longitude,speed,direction
```

a typical couple of lines are.

```
163044,5050.8427,-00049.8211,047.4,107.6
163045,5050.8387,-00049.8012,047.2,106.5
```

Note: I am using Linux, and a Processing sketch to extract the data and save it in a file made unique by including the date and time of its creation in its name, e.g. `posns20150321131751.txt`

I intend to plot this as a trace on an OpenStreetMap which requires data in `osm` format.

This is my Linux command line and error message:

```
[Harry@localhost]~/Gpsbabel% gpsbabel -i xcsv,style=/home/Harry/Gpsbabel/myidata.style -f /GPStalk/posns20150321131751.txt -o osm ~/GPStalk/posn01.osm 
CSV_UTIL : xcsv style "%H%M%S" is missing default.
```

My style file `myidata.style` is:

```
FIELD_DELIMITER    COMMA
IFIELD GMT_TIME,"","%H%M%S"
IFIELD LAT_NMEA
IFIELD LON_NMEA
IFIELD IGNORE
IFIELD IGNORE
```

I find the documentation in the [GPSBabel documentation](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-development/style_define.html) difficult to follow, so my question is, please, where have I gone wrong? In particular, what is wrong with my style file `myidata.style`?

Comment: I would convert to gpx then import to openstreetmap http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting_NMEA_to_GPX#Converting_NMEA_text_dumps_with_gpsbabel upload http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Upload_GPS_tracks

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz, but the problem is that I cannot convert my data to gpx format in the first place, which is why I asked for help.

Comment: NMEA to GPX online http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/gpsbabel/

Comment: Thanks again @Mapperz. I already looked at gpsvisualiser when I first tried to do the conversion. the problem is that, in order to save storage space I have selected only the fields I need, rather than the whole NMEA sentence. So, which of the formats listed in gpsvisualiser do I use? If none apply, how do I define my own (that is the real question)?

Comment: What I really want to know is how to avoid the error message from Gpsbabel.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to my specific problem: To avoid the error messages I had to alter the style file to this, adding extra information to the field definitions:

```
EXTENSION  txt
PROLOGUE Time Latitude Longitude Speed Direction
FIELD_DELIMITER    COMMA
IFIELD GMT_TIME,"","%H%M%S"
IFIELD LAT_NMEA, "", "%09.4f"
IFIELD LON_NMEA,  "", "%010.4f"
IFIELD IGNORE,"", "%s"
IFIELD IGNORE,"", "%s"
```

I also changed to a `.gpx` output file, rather than `.osm` as that seemed more generally useful in other software. So now it produced a .gpx file, but I could not upload it to OpenStreetMap, getting the error message:

`Found no good GPX points in the input data`

The error message has [a link to a site that explains some of the reasons for failure](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/index.php/GPX_Import_Failures), and includes the statement: `Why didn't my GPX file upload properly? Your GPX should consist of trackpoints...` Eventually I realised the significance of this, so altered my style file (added `DATATYPE TRACK`) and command (adding the `-t` option) to treat the data (now from a different set with  the same layout) as a track, instead of waypoints:

```
EXTENSION  txt
PROLOGUE Time,Latitude,Longitude,Speed,Direction
FIELD_DELIMITER    COMMA
DATATYPE TRACK
IFIELD GMT_TIME,"","%H%M%S"
IFIELD LAT_NMEA, "", "%09.4f"
IFIELD LON_NMEA,  "", "%010.4f"
IFIELD IGNORE,"", "%s"
IFIELD IGNORE,"", "%s"

gpsbabel -t -i xcsv,style=/home/Harry/Gpsbabel/myidata.style -f /GPStalk/posns20150321161200.txt -o gpx -F /home/Harry/GPStalk/posn02.gpx
```

This was successful, and I now had a track that I could, at last, upload to OpenStreetMap.

---

I am submitting this to help others who might find themselves facing the same problem, and will accept it as an answer, when I am able, if no more authoritative answer is forthcoming.